# mostrar un string a partir de una letra o signo especifico - php

Tags: php

Tengo una variable que contiene un `string` y quiero que me muestre su contenido a partir de un símbolo especifico, he buscado pero no he podido, quiero que me funcione algo asi:

- *Ya que el punto que se coloca en el ejemplo puede estar en cualquier parte y necesito que siempre me muestre el `string` después del punto sin importar donde este:*

  ```
   $cadena = ".Hola";
   $cortada = substr($continente, ".");
   echo "$cortada";
   // Quiero que el resultado sea: "Hola"
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes convertir el `string` en un `array` y mostrar con `echo` lo que esté en la posición 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$cadena = ".Hola";
//Con la función explode se convierte una cadena en array
$cortada = explode(".",$cadena);
//Acceder al array en la posición 1
//Si la cadena de texto no contiene punto, 
//se notifica o se asigna una cadena vacía
echo $cortada[1] ?? 'La cadena de texto no contiene punto';
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Esto mostrará en pantalla "Hola".

Mas info de la función `explode` [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: no sirve el ejemplo por que estas indicando en que parte esta el punto, si por ejemplo el string fuera dinamico y fuera "hola.hola" no serviría, necesito que siempre muestre el contenido despues del punto sin importar la ubicación.

Comment: Si la cadena dada no tuviera el separador que usas en el `explode` y pasas directo a imprimir `echo "$cortada[1]";` vas a estar ante un caso de *`Undefined offset`*. Para evitarlo, puedes usar *fusión de null*. Aquí un ejemplo completo: `$cadena = "Hola"; $cortada = explode(".",$cadena); echo $cortada[1] ?? '';` Ahí no imprime nada, porque el uso de *fusión de null* neutraliza el aviso, mientras que en el código actual de la respuesta, si pruebas con la cadena `"Hola"` tendrás derecho a un *`Undefined offset`*, no creo que sea un resultado deseable para ese tipo de casos.

Comment: @Giovanny si que funciona, haz la prueba con la cadena de texto que desees, por ejemplo **"Esto es una . Cadena de texto separada"** el `echo` mostrará en pantalla **Cadena de texto separada** ya que le estás indicando que buscas la posición 1 del `array`. Si le indicas la posición 0 mostrará **Esto es una**.

Comment: @A.Cedano tienes razón, editaré la respuesta para agregar tu sugerencia. Gracias por la observación.

Comment: Excelente. Siempre es bueno tener en cuenta los posibles errores para controlarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo con [**`strtok()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtok.php) el cual:

> Divide un string (str) en strings más pequeños (tokens), con cada
> token delimitado por cualquier caracter de token. Es decir, si se
> tiene un string como "Este es un string de ejemplo", se puede
> tokenizar en sus palabras individuales utilizando el caracter de
> espacio como el token.
>
> Nótese que sólo la primera llamada a strtok utiliza el argumento
> string. Cada llamada subsecuente a strtok sólo necesita el token a
> utilizar, ya que realiza un seguimiento del lugar en que se encuentra
> en el string actual. Para volver a empezar, o para dividir una cadena
> nueva, simplemente se llama a strtok de nuevo con el argumento string
> para inicializarlo. Tener en cuenta que se pueden poner tokens
> múltiples como parámetro. El string será tokenizado cuando cualquiera
> de los caracteres en el argumento sea encontrado.

Por ejemplo:

```
$cadena = ".Hola";
$tok = strtok($cadena, ".");
var_dump($tok);
```

**Salida:**

```
string(4) "Hola"
```

---

Si hablamos de un texto que no está normalizado, es decir, no siempre será del tipo `.unaCadenaCualquiera`, sino que puede ser `antesDelPunto.despuesDelPrimerPuntoYNoHayMasPuntos`

Entonces puedes resolverlo aplicando `strtok()` dos veces, la primera con el separador, y la segunda sin nada, algo así:

```
$s ="antesDelPunto.despuesDelPrimerPuntoYNoHayMasPuntos";
strtok( $s, '.' );
echo strtok( '' );
```

**Salida:**

```
despuesDelPrimerPuntoYNoHayMasPuntos
```

Esto sirve también para una cadena del tipo: `antesDelPunto.despuesDelPrimerPunto.YHayMasPuntos` si ese otro punto interior debe conservarse:

```
$s ="antesDelPunto.despuesDelPrimerPunto.YHayMasPuntos";
strtok( $s, '.' );
echo strtok( '' );
```

**Salida:**

```
despuesDelPrimerPunto.YHayMasPuntos
```

En cambio, si lo único que interesa es el contenido `despuesDelPrimerPunto`, `explode()` será la mejor opción, pero se deben controlar posibles casos de *`Undefined offset`*, usando el [operador de fusión de null (??)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php) o bien un operador ternario, si usas PHP inferior a la versión 7.

```
$s ="antesDelPunto.despuesDelPrimerPunto.YHayMasPuntos";
$parts=explode(".",$s);
echo $parts[1] ?? '';
```

**Salida:**

```
despuesDelPrimerPunto
```

Si tienes dudas, pregunta en comentarios. **Soy humano, no soy una IA.**

Comment: lo probé pero tiene un problema si coloco en el string "ss.hola" me aparece "ss" y lo que necesito es que me muestre lo que hay después del punto sin importar donde este.

Comment: @Giovanny en ese caso, lo mejor es usar `explode()` como sugiere DjCrazzy en su respuesta.